# FATAL: database «sampleapp_production» does not exits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

First time here, I hope do it right.

I'm following the railstutorial 3.2 and I'm in section 5.4, in the paragraph above to listing 5.32.

> (In fact, you can just type rake by itself; the default behavior of rake is to
>   run the test suite.)

I used rake by itselft but I have a error since then. When I run: 
"$ bundle exec rake spec" I get this error.

http://pastebin.com/F0wrEkT1

My database.yml is:
http://pastebin.com/tWAgeFTV

My problem is that I don't know why it is asking for production database when I didn't use it yet. And whe I look for the issue I don't find topics about (almost I didn't find it).

Do you have some clues to star looking or to know what is happening?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: why Rails 3.2 any reason ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it is looking for the production DB but you may want to skip ahead.  Just read a little further:
`(In fact, you can just type rake by itself; the default behavior of rake is to run the test suite.) The only caveat is that using rake to run the tests for the current sample application will raise an error since it requires the test database to be prepared properly, a step we’ll defer to Section 6.2.1.`

It recommends running:

```
bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```

Comment: Hello

Finally I resolve the issue. Quick answer, role error in Postgres.

Long answer, I deleted the production database from my database.yml and runed `rake db:create` and `rakedb:migrate`.

Then the console printed that my user couldn't create the DB, so I found that my user didn'y have the rol 'Create DB' in Postgres.

After a little fight the commands `rake db:create` and `rakedb:migrate` finally succeed and the app is running again.

Why did I  remove the production DB? A friend of mine tell I don't that DB right now, so I can remove it. It's made sence for me, what do you think?

Thanks

Comment: I don't usually keep a production DB on my development system.